# Cant access vec4 array in GLSL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

When I try to compile this GLSL code in OpenGL 4.0 I get error 1282

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPos;

uniform mat4 model[100];
uniform mat4 projection;

out int instanceID;

void main()
{
    instanceID = gl_InstanceID;
    gl_Position = projection * model[gl_InstanceID] * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in int instanceID;
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec4 color[100];

void main()
{
    FragColor = color[instanceID];
}
```

The code is regular ShaderProgram creation because I get the error before drawing or anything like that but just in case here is the code:

```
    unsigned int vertex, fragment;

    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    std::string vShaderCode = ReadEntireTextFile(vertPath);
    const char* c_vShaderCode = vShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &c_vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);


    std::string fShaderCode = ReadEntireTextFile(fragPath);
    fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* c_fShaderCode = fShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &c_fShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    // shader Program
    m_RendererID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(m_RendererID, vertex);
    glAttachShader(m_RendererID, fragment);

    glLinkProgram(m_RendererID);
    // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);
    glUseProgram(m_RendererID);
```

I know for sure that the error is because of instanceID because it worked when the shader didn't have that. but I tried to find where the problem is exactly with no luck.

UPDATE:

Made sure shaders were compiled successfully. and turns out they are compiled successfully.

I was able to pinpoint where the error occurs and it was the glUseProgram funtion.

I think the error is because of instanceID because when I change:

```
FragColor = color[instanceID];
```

to

```
FragColor = color[0];
```

the program works.

UPDATE(2):

I solved the problem.
Turns out I had 2 problems one being that I had too many components and I fixed that thanks to one of the answers alerting me.

The other was that I can't put uniforms directly in the fragment shader which I thought you could do.So I put the colors in the vertex shader and passed the one color I needed for the fragment shader.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which gl call caused the error? Can you post that code?

Comment: it was glUseProgram.

Comment: You should check the compile log and see if it compiled correctly.  After calling `glCompileShader()` you need to call  [`glGetShaderInfoLog()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml).

Comment: It does not return anything for both fragment and vertex shaders


and glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &output);
returns true for both shaders.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml), you'll get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` from `glUseProgram()` if "program is not a program object", "program could not be made part of current state", or "transform feedback mode is active". So it must be one of those 3 things.

Comment: Im pretty sure program is an object created by openGL successfully, I'm not really sure about the others though.




you see if i change the fragment shader main function to FragColor = color[0]; it will work so the issue is with instanceID I think.

Comment: Interesting! But at this point, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> uniform mat4 model[100];
> ```

That is way outside of what is guaranteed by the spec. The limit here is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS`, which the spec guarantees to be at least 1024. Since a `mat4` consumes 16 components, that's 64 matrices at most. Now your particular limit might be higher, but you also have the other uniforms in your program, like `color[100]`.

(from comments):

> It does not return anything for both fragment and vertex shaders and `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &output);` returns true for both shaders.

But that does not imply that the *program object* linked successfully. Such ressource limits are usually enforced during linking.

> I'm pretty sure program is an object created by openGL successfully, I'm not really sure about the others though. you see if i change the fragment shader main function to `FragColor = color[0];` it will work so the issue is with `instanceID` I think.

That conclusion does not follow. If you write `color[0]`, it will optimize your `vec4r[100]` array to `vec4[1]`, and you might get below your particular limit.

Comment: I tried changing the size from 100 down to 10 for both the matrices and the vec4's which should be well below 1024 components and I still get the same error :(